# multidimensional array of edittext in android dynamically

Tags: android, multidimensional-array

I am beginner level in android.
how to create multidimensional array in android at runtime.

> i want to create ***multidimensional array of EditText box dynamically*** (at runtime) and all should be disables except the first one.

if any one knows about this please answer.
examples will be appreciated.

this working ok..

```
TextView textView[][] = new TextView[2][2];
```

after this when i tried to assign data it throws nullpointor exception..

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            editText[i][j].setText("data");
        }
    }
```

Comment: "multidimensional array", you mean a Matrix of EditText? can you explain a little bit more what are you trying to get?

Comment: yes matrix of EditText. @SERPRO

Comment: i didnt understand...
will you explain in more detail about the WEBVIEW idea..?????@BicycleDude

Comment: The idea of WebView I guess is to create what you are planning to do with HTML and Javascript and then just open that HTML inside a WebView. Am I right @BicycleDude?

Comment: can't we create matrix of EDITTEXT in andriod,....??????

Comment: yes i had tried but it is giving null pointor exception.

Comment: You declared TextView array and setting contents in the EditText array. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the code for multidimensional array of edittext and to display it as well as to disable it...

```
layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(1);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-1, -1));

    EditText editText[][] = new EditText[2][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            editText[i][j] = new EditText(this);
            editText[i][j].setText("1");
            editText[i][j].setWidth(50);
            layout.addView(editText[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            // editText[i][j].setEnabled(false);
            editText[i][j].setClickable(false);
            editText[i][j].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    setContentView(layout);
```